# Stumped by syntax error only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am stumped by a new error that I am receiving after pushing my code to production yesterday.  I didn't edit anything in the file and it still works fine on my local machine.  This code has been working fine for many months.  Any insights would be appreciated.

Error in logs:

```
23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.235167+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/app/views/line_items/_new_product_form.html.erb:38: warning: else without rescue is useless
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.235974+00:00 app web.1 - - Rendered line_items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239762+00:00 app web.1 - -
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239765+00:00 app web.1 - - ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/views/line_items/_new_product_form.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239767+00:00 app web.1 - - ..., @line_item]), remote: true do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe...
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239769+00:00 app web.1 - - ... ^
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239771+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/app/views/line_items/_new_product_form.html.erb:38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239772+00:00 app web.1 - - ..., @line_item]), remote: true do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe...
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239773+00:00 app web.1 - - ... ^
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239775+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/app/views/line_items/_new_product_form.html.erb:60: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239777+00:00 app web.1 - - end ;@output_buffer.to_s
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239778+00:00 app web.1 - - ^):
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239780+00:00 app web.1 - - 1: <% if params[:request_id] || params[:order_id] %>
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239781+00:00 app web.1 - - 2: <%= simple_form_for ([type, @line_item]), remote: true do |f| %>
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239783+00:00 app web.1 - - 3: <%= f.error_notification %>
» 23:20:49.403 2014-10-01 03:20:49.239784+00:00 app web.1 - - 4: <div class="form-inputs">
```

And the corresponding view (this is a partial and "type" is passed in).

```
<% if params[:request_id] || params[:order_id] %>
<%= simple_form_for ([type, @line_item]), remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :product, :label => "Product Needed", :required => true, :autofocus => true  %>
    <%= f.input :quantity, :required => true, :input_html => { min: 0, max: 10000 }, as: :integer  %>
    <%= f.input :unit, label: "Unit Measurement (leave blank if 'each')", collection: LineItem::UNITS.map { |s| [s.humanize.downcase, s]} %>
    <%= f.input :comments, :required => false, as: :text, :placeholder => "Any additional information you would like to provide." %>
  </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Add Product to List", class: "btn btn-success btn-block", data: {disable_with: "Adding..."} %>
  </div>
<% end %> 
<% else %>
<%= simple_form_for ([type, @line_item]), remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :product, :label => "Product Needed", :required => true, :autofocus => true  %>
    <%= f.input :quantity, :required => true, :input_html => { min: 0, max: 10000 }, as: :integer  %>
    <%= f.input :unit, label: "Unit of Measurement (leave blank if 'each')", collection: LineItem::UNITS.map { |s| [s.humanize.downcase, s]} %> 
    <%= f.input :comments, :required => false, as: :text, :placeholder => "Any additional information you would like to provide." %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add Product to List", class: "btn btn-success btn-block", data: {disable_with: "Adding..."} %>
  </div>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"else without rescue is useless" is ruby for "you have a malformed if". In this case it looks like that is in your call to simple_form_for has parens in the wrong place. I've not used simple_form_for before, but this is what the error looks to be. Or leave the parens off entirely.

```
<%= simple_form_for ([type, @line_item], remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Comment: thanks! leaving off the parens entirely fixed the issue.  Not sure why it worked locally and not in production (heroku).  probably related to different gem versions since heroku updates to most recent.